# Fatal Error - Out of Memory while reading a *.dat file in php

Tags: php, parsing, out-of-memory, file-get-contents, readfile

I have a PHP script which reads data from a file and parse the strings into array like this:

```
    $handle = fopen('syndata.txt', 'r');
    while (!feof($handle)) {
     $data = fgets($handle);

     $convert = explode(",", $data);

     array_push($arrayStr, $convert);

} 
fclose($handle);
```

Where `syndata.dat` is a file of size 2.5 GB. When I run the script, it takes a few minutes to run and after that goves fatal error of "Out of Memory" on line `$data = file_get_contents("syndata.dat");` .

I have tried everything increasing memory limit in php.ini file. Currently, memory_limiy parameter is set to the value -1 which means that unlimited memory. Still it gives fatal error. "Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 520093696)(tried to allocate 519569408)"

Please help me resolving the issue.

Comment: Pretty self explanatory.... you try to load a 2.5GB file into 520MB of memory, what do you expect to happen?.... Use a loop: read a line, process a line, read the next line, process that line, etc

Comment: I am working on 64-bit system.

Comment: But I have used memory_limit: -1 I expect the script to be working. OR please tell me where I should make changes to increase memory? @MarkBaker

Comment: `memory_limit = -1` does not automagically make infinite memory space on your server. Your server still has hardware constraints.

Comment: Okay, what should I do then ? Or how can I remove constraints ? :( @zerkms

Comment: @sana: you have not explained the tasks, hence it's not possible to give any reasonable solution.

Comment: You __DON'T__ remove that constraint.... as I've already said, you rewrite your code to loop through the file one line at a time

Comment: Loop through code one line at a time... ??? How ? :( @MarkBaker

Comment: Easiest way to loop through a file: `$handle = fopen('syndata.dat', 'r');
while (!feof($handle)) {
$data = fgets($handle); //process data from line
}
fclose($handle);` There's plenty of examples in the [php docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php)